# Allow Bat Script to act upon error

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, cmd, xcopy, robocopy

I have a bat file that creates a folder and sub-folders based on a user input. I would like the code to tell me a folder it is trying to create already exists, and furthermore (if possible), if the folder already exists, I would like the code to copy the sub-folders into the pre-existing folder.

My code -

```
@echo off
echo.
:EnterName
set "dest=""
set /P "dest=Enter Name: "
set "dest=%dest:"=%"
if "%dest%" == "" cls & goto EnterName

set "findest=Z:\ProjectIT\copy\%dest%"

robocopy Z:\ProjectIT\copy\xcopy "%findest%" /e /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS

echo Construction folder has been created for "%dest%"
echo.

pause
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: You're looking for the `if exist` command.

Comment: Could you show me how to implement this in my example? My knowledge of code is lacking and I cant make the examples I found online work for me.

Comment: So your goal is to make sure that a folder exists? you don't have to check whether it exists and only create it if not; you can simply create it (`mkdir "\path\to\folder"`) and suppress errors in case it already exists (precede or append `>nul`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `if exist`:

```
@echo off
echo.
:EnterName
set "dest=""
set /P "dest=Enter Name: "
set "dest=%dest:"=%"
if "%dest%"=="" cls & goto EnterName

if exist %findest% (
    echo This folder already exists!
    echo All subfolders will be copied to the existing folder.
)

set "findest=Z:\ProjectIT\copy\%dest%"

robocopy Z:\ProjectIT\copy\xcopy "%findest%" /e /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS

echo Construction folder has been created for "%dest%"
echo.

pause
```

You don't have to modify the code to copy the subfolders. If the folder exists, everything will be copied into it.

Comment: Perfect thank you, I managed to do what I wanted through a combination of this and some loops